# как передать значение $scope из функции в другой $scope вне этой функции

Tags: angularjs

```
  .controller("PostsCtrl",
    function($scope, $http) {
      $http
        .jsonp('https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/feed/load?v=1.0&q=http://www.nbrb.by/RSS/?p=RatesDaily&callback=JSON_CALLBACK')
        .then(function(data, status, headers, config) {
          var str, usd;
          str = data.data.responseData.feed.entries[0].contentSnippet;
          usd = str.match(/.+Доллар США (.+) Российский рубль.*/)[1].replace(/[\s,]/g, '') / 100;
          $scope.ByBankUSD = usd;
        });

      $scope.newscope = ???;
    }
  );
```

подскажите как мне **$scope.ByBankUSD** передать в $scope.newscope

Comment: если коротко - никак. Это особенность того, что происходит асинхронный запрос

Comment: Присоединяюсь: Почему вы не хотите присваивать `ByBankUsd` сразу нужной переменной в `$scope`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
.controller("PostsCtrl",
    function($scope, $http) {

      /* переменные используемые в асинхронных запросах 
         нужно всегда объявлять в контроллере, до их использования */
      $scope.ByBankUSD = ''; 
      $http
        .jsonp('https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/feed/load?v=1.0&q=http://www.nbrb.by/RSS/?p=RatesDaily&callback=JSON_CALLBACK')
        .then(function(data, status, headers, config) {
          var str, usd;
          str = data.data.responseData.feed.entries[0].contentSnippet;
          usd = str.match(/.+Доллар США (.+) Российский рубль.*/)[1].replace(/[\s,]/g, '') / 100;
          $scope.ByBankUSD = usd;
        });

      $scope.$watch('ByBankUSD', function (newValue, oldValue){
          $scope.newscope = newValue;
      });
    }
  );
```

PS. Не проверял, но должно быт так (когда то писал такое уже). И почему ты не хочешь сразу присваивать `ByBankUsd` нужной переменной в `$scope`. Если нужно передать в корень своего модуля, то передавать нужно в `$rootScope`. Там он будет доступен во всех контроллерах подключенных к модулю.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещен в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/38006/discussion-on-answer-by------scope--).

Answer (score 1):

Нашел решение для данной проблемы удобное лично для меня.

Нужно создать до запроса $scope, собственно как у вас и есть.
В .then необходимый для вас результат можно передать за ее пределы .push

То есть:

```
.controller("PostsCtrl",
    function($scope, $http) {

      /* переменные используемые в асинхронных запросах 
         нужно всегда объявлять в контроллере, до их использования */
      $scope.ByBankUSD = ''; 
      $http
        .jsonp('https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/feed/load?v=1.0&q=http://www.nbrb.by/RSS/?p=RatesDaily&callback=JSON_CALLBACK')
        .then(function(data, status, headers, config) {
          var str, usd;
          str = data.data.responseData.feed.entries[0].contentSnippet;
          usd = str.match(/.+Доллар США (.+) Российский рубль.*/)[1].replace(/[\s,]/g, '') / 100;

          $scope.ByBankUSD.push(usd);

        });

      console.log($scope.ByBankUSD)
    }
  );
```

Я пользуюсь таким способом. Работает отлично!